# How to remember the value of a cookie when clicking a search button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am new to Javascript and this site so I'm sorry if this seems newbie.
This is all client side, no server based stuff. Its for my Javascript class.

My teacher has us working with a music store and for this assignment, I need to make it so when I hit my search button, it displays the results like artist and the album from the search box into a page called searchresults.html. When the search button is clicked, I need to get the value of the text box which is suppose to be stored into a cookie/html 5 storage. I then take that cookie, and search my music database for a match. I just can't seem to figure out why this code is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML (index.html)

```
<a target="" href="searchresults.html">
  <img src="img/04.png" id="searchButton" alt="img" onclick="createCookie();">     </a>
</div></div>
<div class="form">
<form method="post" action="" >
<input type="text" id="searchBox">
</form>


</div>
</div>

<script>
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
};
</script>
```

JS (store.js)

```
var Database = [];

var thriller = {
    id: "thriller_MJ",
    title: 'Thriller',
    artist: 'Michael Jackson',
    price: '$12.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1982, 10, 30),
    Quantity: 35,
    link: "albums/thriller.png",
    Tracklinglist: ["Wanna Be Startin Somethin", "Baby Be Mine", "The Girl Is Mine", "Thriller", "Beat It", "Billie Jean", "Human Nature", "P.Y.T. (Pretty Young Thing)", "The Lady In My Life"]
};

var asDaylightDies = {
    id: "asDaylightDies_KSE",
    title: 'As Daylight Dies',
    artist: 'Killswitch Engage',
    price: '$9.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(2006, 11, 21),
    Quantity: 20,
    link: "albums/asDaylightDies.png",
    Tracklinglist: ["Daylight Dies", "This Is Absolution", "The Arms of Sorrow", "Unbroken", "My Curse", "For You", "Still Beats Your Name", "Eye of the Storm", "Break The Silence"]
};

var thriller2 = {
    id: 'thriller_MJ_2',
    title: 'Thriller 2',
    artist: 'Michael Jackson ',
    price: '$12.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1982, 10, 30),
    quantity: 35,
    link: "albums/thriller.png",
    Trackinglist: ["Wanna Be Startin Somethin", "Baby Be Mine", "The Girl Is Mine", "Thriller", "Beat It", "Billie Jean", "Human Nature", "P.Y.T. (Pretty Young Thing)", "The Lady in My Life"]
};

var ledzeppelin = {
    id: "ledzeppelin_LZ",
    title: 'Led Zeppelin',
    artist: 'Led Zeppelin',
    price: '$14.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1969, 01, 12),
    Quantity: 40,
    link: "albums/ledzeppelin.png",
    Tracklinglist: ["Good Times Bad Times", "Babe I'm Gonna Leave You", "You Shook Me", "Dazed And Confused", "Your Time Is Gonna Come", "Black Mountain Side", "Communication Breakdown", "I Can't Quit You Baby", "How Many More Times"]
};

var asDaylightDies2 = {
    id: "asDaylightDies_KSE_2",
    title: 'As Daylight Dies ',
    artist: 'Killswitch Engage 2',
    price: '$9.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(2006, 11, 21),
    Quantity: 20,
    link: "albums/asDaylightDies.png",
    Tracklinglist: ["Daylight Dies", "This Is Absolution", "The Arms of Sorrow", "Unbroken", "My Curse", "For You", "Still Beats Your Name", "Eye of the Storm", "Break The Silence"]
};

var darkSideOfTheMoon = {
    id: "darkSideOfTheMoon_PF",
    title: 'Dark Side of the Moon',
    artist: 'Pink Floyd',
    price: '$7.99',
    releaseDate: new Date(1973, 02, 01),
    Quantity: 60,
    link: "albums/darkSideOfTheMoon.png",
    Trackinglist: ["Speak to Me", "Breathe", "On the Run", "Time", "The Great Gig in the Sky", "Money", "Us and Them", "Any Colour You Like", "Brian Damage", "Eclipse"]
};

Database.push(thriller, asDaylightDies, ledzeppelin, darkSideOfTheMoon, thriller2, asDaylightDies2);

function displayAlbum() {
    for (var i = 0; i < Database.length; i++) {
        alert(Database[i].title + " , " + Database[i].link);
    }
};

//function init() {
    //"use strict";
    //document.getElementById('searchButton').addEventListener('click', //search);
    // searchBox.onsubmit = search;
//};
```

JS (searchresults.js)

```
function getCookie(c_name)  {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
};

 function deleteCookie(name) {
    'use strict';
    document.cookie = encodeURIComponent(name) +
    '=;expire=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT';
};


 function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('searchButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
        getCookie();
        search();

    });
}


    window.onload = init();
```

app.js

```
  function search() {
        'use strict';
        document.getElementById('searchBox').value;
        for (var i = 0; i < Database.length; i++) {
            if (searchBox.value === Database[i].artist) {
            return Database[i].artist, Database[i].album;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: When I look at my searchresults.html file, its giving my addEventListener as null and that it cannot read the property. I know I'm doing something wrong, I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should merge your `init` functions in a load file for example:

```
function init() {    
    document.getElementById('searchButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
        getCookie();
        search(); // I don't see this function
    });
}
```

The `window.onload = init();` should also only be called once. In your case it looks like you're overriding them, depending on which one gets loaded first.

For the sake of too much globals, maybe put everything regarding cookies in a separate library:

```
// mycookies.js
window.MyCookies = {
    createCookie: function(name, value, days){/*c/p code in here*/},
    getCookie: function(c_name){/**/},
    deleteCookie(name){/**/}
};
```

Same for your Database:

```
// database.js
window.DataBase = {
    thriller: {/**/},
    thriller2: {/**/},
    asDaylightDies: {/**/},
    asDaylightDies2: {/**/},
    darkSideOfTheMoon: {/**/}
};
```

Then consider the above, your "tools" so to speak. Your logic for example:

```
// searchalbum.js
(function(db, cookies){
    'strict';
    window.SearchAlbum = {
        init: function(){
            this.cacheItems();

            if (this.container.length){
                this.bindEvents();
                this.lastSearch('album');
            }
        },

        cacheItems: function(){
            // Make sure the click event bubbles down to the img.
            // If not, put the id on the anchor tag
            // If you have many search items on the page, change to .getElementsByClassName
            this.container = document.getElementById('searchButton');
        },

        bindEvents: function(){
            var self = this;

            this.container.addEventListener('click', function(){
                self.search();
                cookies.createCookie('album', this.src || this.alt);
            });
        },

        search: function(){
            for (var item in db){
                if (db.hasOwnProperty(item)){
                    alert(item.title + " , " + item.link);
                }
            }
        },

        lastSearch: function(name){
            var cookie = cookies.getCookie(name);

            if (cookie){
                alert('last search: ' + cookie);
            }
        }
    };

    window.onload = SearchAlbum.init;
}(window.DataBase || {}, window.MyCookies || {}));
```

Comment: So I changed the post to add where the search function was coming from. Forgot it was coming from a different JS file. Should be showing now. I tried your code but it still is giving me the error that my Event Listener is null.

Comment: What browser are you testing on? `eventListener` is available since IE9.